# REPLACE CHR(32) in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have problem here, the record in database ends with no space. the value is EXT:
but when i select with this query :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COL_CONTENT,CHR(10),'\n'),CHR(9),'\t'),CHR(32),'\s') FROM TABLE_A;
```

the record become :

```
+6221\s29023070\sEXT\s:\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s
```

Actually in database after EXT: dont have any characters or space. but the record still show so many \s after EXT:

Comment: How do you check you have no spaces ? Can you please post the result of `length(col_content)` and `length(trim(col_content))`?

Comment: i just check from db software and its stuck after EXT: then there is the value for length is 80 and length trim is 76

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column is of `CHAR(n)` datatype and the string you have entered does not have `n` characters then Oracle will pad the data with space (`CHR(32)`) characters until it has exactly `n` characters.

The typical solution is not to use `CHAR(n)` and use a `VARCHAR2(n)` datatype.

However you could also use `RTRIM()`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            RTRIM( COL_CONTENT ),
            CHR(10),
            '\n'
          ),
          CHR(9),
          '\t'
        ),
        CHR(32),
        '\s'
      )
FROM TABLE_A;
```

(Note: not using `TRIM()` as Oracle only pads the right-hand side and if you trim the whitespace from both ends then you may strip the leading part of your string.)

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but RTRIM makes all \s disappeared, i want to keep track any space character as '\s'